# Android: Bluetooth Trouble opening server socket

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I am currently in the middle of building an Android app with bluetooth capabilties and am having some issue establishing a server socket. End goal currently is to exchange strings between devices and then pass those back to the main activity. When attempting to open a socket I continually get the error:

> W/System.err: java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
>           at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readAll(BluetoothSocket.java:741)
>           at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readInt(BluetoothSocket.java:753)
>   W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:375)
>           at com.example.main.BluetoothConnectionService$ConnectThread.run(BluetoothConnectionService.java:98)

I've had no luck troubleshooting this myself, any advice you may be able to give me is appreciated! It might be worth mentioning that this is my first time working with Bluetooth in android...

````
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.UUID;

public class BluetoothConnectionService {
    private static final String TAG = "BluetoothConnectionService";
    private static final String appName = "Bluetooth App";
    private static final UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("8ce255c0-200a-11e0-ac64-0800200c9a66");
    private final BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private Context mcontext;

    private AcceptThread mInsecureAcceptThread;
    private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
    private BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
    private UUID deviceUUID;
    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;

    public BluetoothConnectionService(Context context){
        this.mcontext = context;
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        start();
    }

    private class AcceptThread extends Thread{
        private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

        public AcceptThread() {
            BluetoothServerSocket temp = null;
            try {
                temp = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(appName, uuid);
                Log.d(TAG,"AcceptThread: Setting up Server using: " + uuid);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG,"AcceptThread: IOException: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            mmServerSocket = temp;
        }
        public void run(){
            Log.d(TAG,"run: AcceptThread Running.");

            BluetoothSocket socket = null;

            try {
                socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
                Log.d(TAG, "run: RFCOM server socket accepted connection.");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG,"RunThread: IOException: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            if(socket != null){
                connected(socket,mmDevice);
            }

        }

        public void cancel(){
            try{
                mmServerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
               Log.e(TAG,"cancel: Close of AcceptThread ServerSocket failed. " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }


    private class ConnectThread extends Thread{
        private BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device,UUID uuid){
            mmDevice = device;
            deviceUUID = uuid;
        }

        public void run(){
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            Log.i(TAG,"Run mConnectThread");

            try {
                tmp = mmDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(deviceUUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG,"could not create insecureRFcommSocket" + e.getMessage());
            }
            mmSocket = tmp;
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            try {
                mmSocket.connect();
                Log.d(TAG,"run: Socket connected");
            } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
                try{
                    mmSocket.close();
                    Log.d(TAG,"run: Closed Socket");
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Log.e(TAG,"Socket Connection failed to close.");
                }
            }
            connected(mmSocket,mmDevice);
        }
        public void cancel(){
            try{
                Log.d(TAG,"cancel: Closing Client Socket");
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG,"cancel: close() of mmSocket in ConnectThread failed. " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized void start(){
        Log.d(TAG,"start");

        if(mConnectThread != null){
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }
        if(mInsecureAcceptThread == null){
            mInsecureAcceptThread = new AcceptThread();
            mInsecureAcceptThread.start();
        }
    }

    public void startclient(BluetoothDevice device, UUID uuid){
        Log.d(TAG, "startclient: Started");
       Log.d(TAG,"Connecting Bluetooth");
        mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device,uuid);
        mConnectThread.start();
    }

    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ConnectedTrhead: Starting");
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;
            Log.d(TAG,"Bluetooth Connected");
            try {
                tmpIn = mmSocket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            this.mmInStream = tmpIn;
            this.mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run(){
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;

            while(true){
                try {
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    String incomingMessage = new String(buffer, 0 ,bytes);
                    Log.d(TAG,"Input Stream" + incomingMessage);

                    Intent incomingMessageIntent = new Intent("incomingMessage");
                    incomingMessageIntent.putExtra("themessage",incomingMessage);
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mcontext).sendBroadcast(incomingMessageIntent);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG,"write: Error writing to inputstream" + e.getMessage());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        public void write(byte[] bytes){
            String text = new String(bytes, Charset.defaultCharset());
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG,"write: Error writing to outputstream" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        public void cancel(){
            try{
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG,"Socket should not be closed");
            }
        }
    }

    private void connected(BluetoothSocket mmSocket, BluetoothDevice mmDevice){
        Log.d(TAG,"connected: Starting.");

        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
        mConnectedThread.start();
    }

    public void write(byte[] out){
        ConnectedThread r;
        mConnectedThread.write(out);
    }

}```
````